# Android java. Create a folder and a file in the local DCIM folder

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to create a folder structure inside of the local DCIM folder of an Android phone?

Android 5.1

I need to create the next folder structure.

```
DCIM/Camera/Notes
```

and create a file there.

I do the next:

```
    File internalDcimDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
    internalDcimDir = new File(internalDcimDir, "Camera");
    internalDcimDir = new File(internalDcimDir, "Notes");
    internalDcimDir.mkDirs();
```

And when I try to create a file no exceptions occure

```
 File file = new File(internalDcimDir, noteFileName);
```

And when I write something..

```
    FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {

        OutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fo.write(content.getBytes());
        fo.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

it occures that there is no file and even dirs created.

May be I am doing something wrong. What can it be?

Comment: did you remmembered to add permissions on your app manifest?  **<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>**

Comment: `internalDcimDir.mkDirs()`. Only call mkdirs if the directories do not exist. Use .exists(). And check the return value of mkdirs as it will return false if it fails. In that case display a toast and return. As it does not make sense trying to creats a file in a directory that does not exist.

Comment: `when I try to create a file no exceptions occure`. You are not creating a file there. Only  File object. The file is created by new FileOutputStream().

Comment: I forgot that internal phone memory is treated as External Storage. So I forgot to add the permission mentioned. 

And yes, I made the whole dirs creation wrong. Thanks for the help. I hope it'll help me. 

I'll write here when I accomplish my task

Thanks!

Comment: @yurart: and you didn't write the answer as your promised. Sad( people who ask for help and don't provide the solution they asked for to help people after them. Please give back to the community